# Create a plot with two x-axis with different scales in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to create a plot with two x-axis in python, but these two x-axis have totally different scales.

For example, I have two large data sets and I ran the linear regression for them and got the graph. And I then want to add one more x-axis on the top to show the frequency of y points.

```
ax1.scatter(testx, testy)
ax1.plot(X, fittedvalues)
```

Like the code, I want to plot the histogram of variable testy in the same graph.

Could anyone offer some suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: matplotlib's `twinx` is what you're looking for. http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: Yup, thank you. I read it before but still confuse how to have different scales. Like, in my existing graph, x-axis is about the actual price of variable testx.  However in the new x-axis, I want to have it about the frequency of variable testy